# Processing POST request with data encoded as multipart/form-data

Tags: angular, typescript, go

I am using angular and typescript to send my file in a post request body to backend which is in golang, where it parses the file and uploads the data in file in the DB. When I am sending the file from Postman, the file is read and the data is being inserted in the DB successfully, which means my backend code is working just fine. When I am sending it from Typescript, it is giving me EOF error. Please find the code below -

Angular -

```
<input (change)="getFile($event.target.value,$event)" type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" class="form-control"
            accept=".csv" />
```

TypeScript -

```
file: File
getFile(event_value, event){
        this.file = event.target.files[0];
        fileUpload(this.file)
    }

fileUpload(file: any){     
    let url = `abc/abc/abc`
    let header = {'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data; boundary=----abc', 'Authorization': 'authorizationToken'}

    return this.http.post(url, {"file": file}, {headers: header})
    .map((response: Response) => response.json())
    .catch(this.handleError)
  }
```

Error in Go:

```
{"data":{"error":"multipart: NextPart: EOF","code":102,"data":null,"url":""},"level":"error","msg":"{multipart: NextPart: EOF 102 \u003cnil\u003e }","time":"2019-02-12T11:33:00-05:00"}
```

Am I missing something, that needs to be sent in the header?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What happens if you send the same data [using `curl`](https://ec.haxx.se/http-multipart.html)? I mean, you have to figure out what part is at fault: your TS sending code or your Go receiving/processing code.

Comment: @ThunderCat is there a way to check if the file is being sent along with the content in post body?

Comment: @ThunderCat I am using FormFile provided by http package which returns the file for the provided key and that function is throwing EOF error. Also, I tried reading the file the way you said, it still doesn't work. Is there anything else I need to send in POST request?

Comment: @ThunderCat your piece of code does make a bunch of numbers get printed on the terminal in go and yes FormFile is returning the error. I had guessed so, the error is because of the malformed request body but what is it that I need to add in the request body along with the file? I have specified everything I am sending in the post request above. I am really sorry if it is supposed to be obvious, this is because I am new to Go.